# Which is the best criterion for DF-GLS lag selection?

Tags: stata, stationarity, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

When you have an output such as this in Stata for `dfgls`:

```
               DF-GLS tau      1% Critical       5% Critical      10% Critical
  [lags]     Test Statistic        Value             Value             Value
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    10           -1.615           -3.732            -2.713            -2.430
    9            -2.306           -3.732            -2.766            -2.484
    8            -2.320           -3.732            -2.821            -2.539
    7            -2.163           -3.732            -2.877            -2.594
    6            -1.920           -3.732            -2.933            -2.648
    5            -2.007           -3.732            -2.988            -2.701
    4            -2.766           -3.732            -3.041            -2.750
    3            -2.638           -3.732            -3.090            -2.795
    2            -2.518           -3.732            -3.134            -2.836
    1            -2.674           -3.732            -3.171            -2.870

Opt Lag (Ng-Perron seq t) = 0 [use maxlag(0)]
Min SC   =  13.14424 at lag  1 with RMSE  660.2994
Min MAIC =  13.41831 at lag  1 with RMSE  660.2994
```

Which is the best criterion? For now, I'm using the MAIC. If I choose the optimal lag as 0, I strongly reject null hypothesis in this case.

And if the results of the `dfgls` contradict the results of `kpss` and `pperron` (as for the lag selection of MAIC)?

Comment: I noticed you have not accepted any of the two answers, but I feel both of them are quite adequate (although I should not be evaluating my own work). That's just a heads-up :)

Answer (score 3):

Look at the `varsoc` command. It gives you 6 different criteria for lag-selection for VAR models but is also applicable to these tests. You would type: `varsoc` *varname*.

Another way to select the maximum lag length is to use the so-called Schwert criterion: lag length $=\left[12\cdot\left(\frac{T}{100}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}\right]$. A good rule of thumb is to use as many lags as to remove all autocorrelation. Note that Monte Carlo evidence has shown that it is better to include too many lags than too few.

Regarding the PP (Newey-West correction) and KPSS tests versus the DF-GLS then I would go with the DF-GLS (since it is more efficient than the PP) but I would also implement the tests below. I remember reading a paper on the KPSS test saying that it basically has a similar problem of low power which the SDF and PP test have but I cannot find it. Try some googling and you might be luckier and that is why I would go with the DF-GLS test. Eric Zivot has some good lecture notes on unit roots: [Unit Root Tests](http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ584/notes/unitroot.pdf).

Remember that when running unit root tests that structural breaks/level shifts will bias your test towards not rejecting the null of a unit root while large outliers will bias your test of rejecting the null of a unit root. Because of this it is often a good idea to run a battery of unit root tests and make sure they give the same results. I know that Stata also has the Phillips-Perron (PP) and the regular ADF unit root tests (I didn't see that you had mentioned these tests until I had written my answer. Sorry!). Furthermore there are Stata modules out there for more automated tests.

One is the KPSS test has the null-hypothesis of stationarity or trend stationarity vs the alternative hypotheses of a random walk or a random walk with drift. You can find the KPSS module here: [KPSS: Stata module to compute Kwiatkowski-Phillips-Schmidt-Shin test for stationarity](https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s410401.html)

Another test you should look at is the Zivot-Andrews unit test which allows for an endogenous break in the trend or intercept of the time series of interest. You can find the Zivot-Andrews unit root test here: [ZANDREWS: Stata module to calculate Zivot-Andrews unit root test in presence of structural break](https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s437301.html).

Then there is the Clemente, Montañés and Reyes unit root which allows for two structural breaks and allows for both additive and innovational outliers. This Stata command also includes the one break Perron and Vogelsang unit root test. The command can be found here: [CLEMAO_IO: Stata module to perform unit root tests with one or two structural breaks](https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s444302.html).

I would recommend you to look at the time series to see if there could be any structural breaks or level shifts there and also run the unit root tests which allow for these breaks. If you are quite certain that there might be a break you could also use a Chow test to determine the break and then use the Perron (1989) unit root test which allows for a break. In this test you will have to specify the break yourself while in the above tests they find the most likely break by minimizing some test statistic. I didn't link to the papers which these tests are from but a quick Google search will find them for you.

There might be some more unit root Stata modules but those are the ones that come to mind now. If you want to look for yourself then there is an excellent page here: [Boston College Department of Economics Statistical Software Components](https://ideas.repec.org/s/boc/bocode.html).

Answer (score 2):

Ng & Perron ["Lag Length Selection and the Construction of Unit Root Tests with Good Size and Power"](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1468-0262.00256/abstract) (2001) (or a working paper version freely accessible [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.194.4674&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) define modified information criteria (modified AIC = MAIC and modified BIC = MBIC) for lag length selection in the context of unit root testing with the modified Phillips-Perron (MPP) test, and also with the DF-GLS test. They show that MAIC is the preferred criterion with the best size/power properties among AIC, BIC, MAIC and MBIC.

Further, Perron & Qu ["A simple modification to improve the finite sample
properties of Ng and Perron's unit root tests"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165176506002138) (2007) (or a working paper version freely accessible [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.147.9045&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) show that it pays to use OLS detrending instead of GLS detrending when defining MAIC/MBIC; that yields both better size and better power properties.

Both papers show that the MPP test performs (at least somewhat) better than the DF-GLS test.

Since I am not a Stata user, I cannot comment much on the particular functions available in Stata. But I know Stata typically has good documentation, so you should be able to find the relevant information there.

I do not have a good answer to the question of KPSS test against the unit root tests.