# How to compute the lag length for unit root test

Tags: r, model-selection, lags, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have to do unit root test in R. I want to know which method to use in `tseries::adf.test()` in order to compute the lag length.

With other functions, such as `CADFtest()` and `ur.df()`, we can select the criterion to compute the lag length. I've see that `adf.test()` uses a formula equal `k`, but I don't understand the meaning of that formula.

Comment: Check [these questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/augmented-dickey-fuller+lags), maybe you will find an answer. Now do you want to know how to select lag order in R (a question about using software, thus off topic) or what the theoretically optimal lag order is (on topic)?

Comment: Regarding the latter question, perhaps references from [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151423/which-is-the-best-criterion-for-df-gls-lag-selection/151465#151465) will be useful. The answer considers DF-GLS and MPP tests, but there may be some discussion about the vanilla ADF test in the references.

Comment: Sorry but I've formulated the question in a wrong way, don't know why. What I want to know is which method use `adf.test()` by default to compute the lag length. Sorry again. Maybe I've to edit the question?

Comment: Of course, that would be good!